# Any solution for negativ result after subtraction in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, subtraction, negative-number

I am relative new in coding and I have following problem: I have 13 number inputs, that are all floats and come automatically after an user input (class=“autoValue”). They must be added together. Then the result must be used for Math.exp function. 
My problem is that one of the numbers is negativ (-5) and though the subtraction is valid operation in JQuery the final result is almost always negativ (the function is triggered after each user input). So I get NaN result...

- How can I overcome this issue?
- Did I do the Math wrong?
- Is my code ok?
- Is the part with exponential right?

Unfortunately, all solution that I found online don’t solve my problem, so I need some help. 
**EDIT:** I added a Part of the HTML (the full code is way too long). Thanks in advance!

```js
//get gender
$('input').click(function(e){
if ($("#demo09a").is(':checked')){
$("#2").val(0.65);
}
else {
$("#2").val(0);
}
})


 function getScore() {
  var sum = 0;
  $(".autoValue").each(function() {
    sum += +this.value;
  });
  console.log("sum:" + sum)
  var ex = Math.exp(sum);
  console.log("ex:" + ex)
  var result = ex / (1 + ex);
  var finalResult = result.toFixed(2);
  if (isNaN(finalResult)) finalResult = 0;
  $('#result').val((finalResult));
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.trigger').click(function(event) {
    getScore();
  });
  $('.triggeriii').keyup(function(event) {
    getScore();
  });
  $('.triggeriii').blur(function(event) {
    getScore();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="result" type=“text” readonly="true">Result <br />
<input id="1" class="autoValue" type=“text” value="-3.0877706">Field 1 <br \>
<input id="demo09a" class="trigger" type="radio" name="gender" value="1">female
<input id="demo09b" class="trigger" type="radio" name="gender" value="0">male<br />
<input id="2" class="autoValue" type=“text” name="2" readonly="true">Field 2
```

Comment: what do you mean by `sum += +this.value;`?

Comment: `+this.value` coerces the string value from the input to a number. It's then added to `sum`. @edkeveked

Comment: Yes @Andy, you're right!

Comment: @edkeveked This part works. I checkt it by assign the result to the field “result” and it made the right calculation. The problem came when I include the negativ value in the calculation. Then I received a NaN... that’s my problem.

Comment: Can you provide a list of the numbers so we can do some checking?

Comment: If you can add a part of your HTML, it will be great!

Comment: @Andy field 1 - (-5.123); 2 - 0.65; 3 - 1.124; 4 - 0.887; 5 - 0.5671; 6 - 1.009; 7 - 0.326; 8 - 9.45; 9 - 0.6571; 10 - 0.45221; 11 - 0.4512; 12 - 0.4186; 13 - 0.3184. The number 1 is always in use (like coefficient). All others come if a radio button is selected or particular after user’s Input. If the button is not selected or the input fails the value is “0” for each of the fields except 1. That’s why the function is fired after every radio button (class “trigger”) or number input (class “triggeriii”). Thanks

Comment: @edkeveked I’ll try to simplify it and then add it. Just need some time.

Comment: I think maybe You have to use `$(this).val()` instead of `this.value` ?

Comment: @YouneL why? that is what `val()` will do internally ... return the native property of the element represented by `this`

Comment: @edkeveked the part of the html is added. It is basically the same for all 13 fields - radio button check -> value is assigned to a field -> this field is used for further calculations. Problem - field 1 is with negativ number and the result is negativ and then the code returns NaN... how to deal with this?

Comment: @YouneL all calculations (adding) works perfect this way. The problem is that the first number in this role is negative and the result is negativ. Thus the code returns NaN. This is my problem. How to overcome this?

Comment: Maybe I am reading this wrong, but I think you just want a positive number. would getting the absolute value work for you? Math.abs('put the sum variable here');

Comment: Exp function is from R to R, there is no need to do abs

Comment: @SynchroDynamic - thanks for answer but Nop. I need the result as by real-lege math - negative or positive- because it will be used afterwards for Math.exp(). So I don’t need to convert the negativ value to positive, besides if i needed this i will just assign a positive value instead (it is like a coefficient).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working. I used different negative numbers (-5, -4) in the input `field1`and it worked.
Maybe you are doing some other computations in your code that might be causing your issue. Given your code, with an input in the `field1`, we have the same output independently that `male` or `female` was checked.

```js
//get gender
function triggerComputation(){
$('input').click(function(e){
if ($("#demo09a").is(':checked')){
$("#2").val(0.65);
}
else {
$("#2").val(0);
}
})

getScore()
}



 function getScore() {
  var sum = 0;
  $(".autoValue").each(function() {
    sum += +this.value;
  });
  console.log("sum:" + sum)
  var ex = Math.exp(sum);
  console.log("ex:" + ex)
  var result = ex / (1 + ex);
  console.log("result:"+result);
  var finalResult = result.toFixed(2);
  if (isNaN(finalResult)) finalResult = 0;
  $('#result').val((finalResult));
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.trigger').click(function(event) {
    getScore();
  });
  $('.triggeriii').keyup(function(event) {
    getScore();
  });
  $('.triggeriii').blur(function(event) {
    getScore();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="result" type=“text” readonly="true">Result <br />
<input id="1" class="autoValue" type=“text” value="-3.0877706">Field 1 <br \>
<input id="demo09a" class="trigger" type="radio" name="gender" value="1">female
<input id="demo09b" class="trigger" type="radio" name="gender" value="0">male<br />
<input id="2" class="autoValue" type=“text” name="2" readonly="true">Field 2

<button onclick="triggerComputation()">compute</button>
```

Comment: @Pussyfer, could you give me an input and the output you expect?

Comment: Thanks mate! I checked my code throughout and found out that there was a typos - it was a “dash” instead of “minus” sign in the “field 1” and this is why the code returned NaN... thanks for helping me solving this issue.

Comment: @Pussyfer, Great you soved it!

Answer (score 0):

use JavaScript abs() Method

absolute value: `Math.abs(-3.0877706);`

result : `3.0877706`

Comment: I need the result as it is - negativ or positive - because the result is used afterwards for Math.exp().